# It is not deleting a database row when I click on the Cancel button

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sql, ajax

I have a "Cancel" button where when the user clicks on it, it resets the source and removes the iframe so that the file does not get uploaded into the server after the user has clicked on the "Cancel" button. This is working fine.

But the problem I have is that also after the user has clicked on the "Cancel" button, I dont want it to insert the row into the database. But as that I have stated that if file is uploaded then insert a row into the database displaying the file name, then what I was thinking of doing was that if the "Cancel" button was clicked on, then it will navigate to the "cancelimage.php" page where it will delete the row. So technically the row is inserted and then deleted if the "Cancel" button is clicked on.

The problem is that it is not deleting the row, it is only inserting the row. How can I get it to delete the row in the database?

Below is the startImageUpload() function where it starts uploading and where the cancel button function is featured:

```
function startImageUpload(imageuploadform){

$(".imageCancel").on("click", function(event) {

              $("iframe[name='upload_target']").attr("src", "javascript:'<html></html>'");
          return stopImageUpload();

    jQuery.ajax("cancelimage.php")

});       
      return true;
}
```

Below is the code where it contains the upload script (imageupload.php) where it inserts a row into the database:

```
<?php

session_start();


$username="xxx";
$password="xxx";
$database="xxx";

mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);

mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$result = 0;

      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"],
      "ImageFiles/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);
      $result = 1;

        $imagesql = "INSERT INTO Image (ImageFile) 
        VALUES ('ImageFiles/".mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['fileImage']['name'])."')";

mysql_query($imagesql);

      }

      mysql_close();

?>
```

finally below is the cancelimage.php page where it is suppose to delete the row from the database:

```
<?php

$username="xxx";
$password="xxx";
$database="xxx";

mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);

mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

    echo "File Upload was Canceled";

        $imagecancelsql = "DELETE FROM Image 
        WHERE ImageFile = 'ImageFiles/". mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['fileImage']['name'])."'";

    mysql_query($imagecancelsql);

    mysql_close();


?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call cancelimage.php `$_FILES['fileImage']['name']` will not contain the name anymore. It only contains the file name at the page where it is uploaded. You will need to store the name in a cookie, session or something else.

---

Edit:

Never ever trust the input from a client:

`move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"],
      "ImageFiles/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);`

What if I uploaded something with the filename '../imageupload.php'. Your site would be broken ;) Even worse, I could inject all sorts of nasty code.

Answer (score 0):

> return stopImageUpload();

you statement reads like the stop image is handled and the execution returns out. the following statement `jQuery.ajax("cancelimage.php")` never gets called.